# Nhibernate: mapping two different properties between the same 2 entities

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a Class A:

```
public class ClassA
{
      public int ID {get; private set;}
      public string Code {get; private set;}
      public ClassB B {get; private set;}
      public IList<ClassB> ListB {get; private set;}

}
```

And a ClassB:

```
public class ClassB
{
      public int ID {get; private set;}
      public string Code {get; private set;}
      public ClassA A {get; private set;}
      //some other attributes...
}
```

And the Mappings:

```
public ClassAMap()
{
    Table("ClassA");

    Id(classA => classA .ID, "ID").GeneratedBy.Identity();
    Map(classA  => classA.Code, "Code").Unique().Not.Nullable();
   //HERE IS THE PROBLEM: --------
    References(classA  => classA.B,"IDClassB").Cascade.SaveUpdate(); 
   //-----
    HasMany(classA  => classA.ListB).Table("ClassB").KeyColumn("IDClassA").AsBag().Not.LazyLoad().Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
}
```

ClassB Mappings:

```
public ClassBMap()
{
    Table("ClassB");
    Id(classB => classB.ID).GeneratedBy.Identity();
    References(classB => classB.A, "IDClassA").ForeignKey("ID").Cascade.SaveUpdate();

}
```

The mappings for ListB in classA worked ok, because at first the was only ListB property and not B, when i had to map B i tried this:

```
References(classA  => classA.B,"IDClassB");
```

The mapping test failed because B wasn't saved, so i did this:

```
References(classA  => classA.B,"IDClassB").Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

This time B was saved, but by saving B, classA was inserted two times, by A.B and by B.A.

How can i solve this problem? Why does it work for the ListB property and not for the B property? Thanks

Comment: OK, i need to have another property, a boolean in classB indicating if its being referenced as a B from classA or a ListB element. 

in classB:

public bool isB{get; private set;}

now i have to say to nhibernate that when i get B for classA i have to go to classB table and get it with IDClassA and IsB = true

Comment: Myabe i will put B as a listB element too, but with the IsB boolean set to true, that solves this problem...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a list in classA that contains B and listB elements, the properties B and listB now are "views" over that new list. To distinguish former listB elements from former B properties in this new list, i added a boolean in classB, if true is B is false is listB element.